# Remove duplicate row based on specific column value

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table data like

```
+--------------------------------------+--------------------------------------+-----------+--------+
|            conversationid            |            participantid             | mediatype | rownum |
+--------------------------------------+--------------------------------------+-----------+--------+
| 01fda91b-6001-4904-b0bc-8c61aec654b4 | 13f954cb-4acb-4ab9-89e7-c48ece23a043 | callback  |      1 |
| 01fda91b-6001-4904-b0bc-8c61aec654b4 | 13f954cb-4acb-4ab9-89e7-c48ece23a043 | voice     |      2 |
| 0519386a-2b8f-403c-b65b-fd8cc3c09a32 | b033fe2f-a58c-4973-8006-54561b5a5bf7 | voice     |      1 |
| 085adea7-1deb-45d8-ae61-639255a689ce | 4151d364-5740-4dcf-b756-9772efaacb26 | voice     |      1 |
| 0c50e9c5-cbe0-4da5-9a8c-976efea255b2 | 8f1ee999-8454-4db9-8c24-68e773350f39 | callback  |      1 |
| 138da3c8-c118-4ddf-b294-57301261eb97 | cf2b643e-b07f-46c8-a52c-0cb5492e6485 | voice     |      1 |
| 613c51c6-3c8b-4b53-91de-de3cc004fa92 | 54a84468-e452-4820-9c8a-89904ff97d8d | callback  |      1 |
| 613c51c6-3c8b-4b53-91de-de3cc004fa92 | 54a84468-e452-4820-9c8a-89904ff97d8d | voice     |      2 |
+--------------------------------------+--------------------------------------+-----------+--------+
```

I'm trying to remove the duplicate data based on specific column value (mediatype).

I need to exclude the rows with meditype "voice" only when there is two value (voice,Callback) for conversationid and participationid combo.

I tried the code

```
;with cte as(select conversationid,participantid ,
mediatype,row_number() over (partition by conversationid,participantid order by mediatype ) 
as rownum from #temp
)select * from cte where rownum=1 
order by conversationid,participantid ,mediatype
```

But the result is not based on specific value but it excludes based on alphabets. I need a condition where the row should be excluded when duplicate row has mediatype as voice. for other unique rows when there is no callback value, it should return mediatype voice.

Answer (score 2):

You want all the rows with `mediatype = 'callback'` or `mediatype = 'voice'` if there is not also `mediatype = 'callback'`.
Apply these conditions in the WHERE clause:

```
select * from tablename t
where 
  mediatype = 'callback'
  or 
  not exists (
    select 1 from tablename
    where conversationid = t.conversationid and participantid = t.participantid
          and mediatype <> t.mediatype
  )
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=b03dcee7f6f271344da810cc4366784b).
Results:

```
> conversationid                       | participantid                        | mediatype | rownum
> :----------------------------------- | :----------------------------------- | :-------- | -----:
> 01fda91b-6001-4904-b0bc-8c61aec654b4 | 13f954cb-4acb-4ab9-89e7-c48ece23a043 | callback  |      1
> 0519386a-2b8f-403c-b65b-fd8cc3c09a32 | b033fe2f-a58c-4973-8006-54561b5a5bf7 | voice     |      1
> 085adea7-1deb-45d8-ae61-639255a689ce | 4151d364-5740-4dcf-b756-9772efaacb26 | voice     |      1
> 0c50e9c5-cbe0-4da5-9a8c-976efea255b2 | 8f1ee999-8454-4db9-8c24-68e773350f39 | callback  |      1
> 138da3c8-c118-4ddf-b294-57301261eb97 | cf2b643e-b07f-46c8-a52c-0cb5492e6485 | voice     |      1
> 613c51c6-3c8b-4b53-91de-de3cc004fa92 | 54a84468-e452-4820-9c8a-89904ff97d8d | callback  |      1
```

Comment: Do you think you'd get short-circuiting of the subquery if you added `mediatype = 'voice' and` before the `not exists ...` ?

Comment: @shawnt00 The requirement is to remove `mediatype = 'voice'` if there is also `mediatype = 'callback'`, so no it would be wrong.

Comment: Boolean algebra: A + B = A + ~AB. In this setting the negation of *mediatype = callback* is *mediatype = voice*.I tried the query before I posted so I know they both work. But by the same token, short-circuiting would probably prevent it from getting there in the first place.

Comment: The requirement is: `NOT (mediatype = 'voice' AND EXISTS (mediatype = 'callback'))` which is equivalent to: `mediatype = 'callback' OR NOT EXISTS...'`. Now, short circuit is never guaranteed in any rdbms.

Answer (score 0):

I'm actually not clear why your original query didn't work (as "voice" rows will be #1 when no "callback" precedes them) but here's another way that works when these are the only three column values you need in the result:

```
select conversationid, participant, min(mediatype) as mediatype
from #temp
group by conversationid, participantid;
```

If you don't want to rely on the alphabetical ordering then use a case expression:

```
select conversationid, participant,
    case min(case mediatype when 'callback' then 1 when 'voice' then 2 end)
        when 1 then 'callback' when 2 then 'voice' end as mediatype
from #temp
group by conversationid, participantid;
```